# How can I easily check if a string starts with 4N spaces?

Tags: python

How can I easily check if a string starts with `4*N` spaces, where `N` is a positive integer?

My current code is:

```
def StartsWith4Nspaces(string):
    count = 0
    for c in string:
        if c == ' ':
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count > 0 and count % 4 == 0
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to write this down?

I'm kinda hoping for a single statement (though anything cleaner than the above would be great).

Thank you.

Comment: Does a string starting with `4*N + 1` spaces match your requirement of starting with `4*N` spaces? As in do you the number of spaces at the start of the string to be *exactly* `4*N`, or just for the string to start with `4*N` spaces.

Answer (score 5):

You can just check for it like so:

```
my_string[:4*N] == ' ' * 4*N
```

You can also convert this check of yours into a `lambda`:

```
check = lambda my_string, N: my_string[:4*N] == ' ' * 4*N
```

and call it as:

```
check('  asdas', 2) # -> True
check('  asdas', 3) # -> False
```

Or if you want to hardcode the `N` for whatever reason (`N = 3`):

```
check = lambda my_string: my_string[:12] == ' ' * 12
```

---

> EDIT: If the *4Nth + 1* character is required to **not** be a space, you can incorporate that into your `lambda`:

```
check_strict = lambda my_string, N: my_string[:4*N] == ' ' * 4*N and my_string[4*N + 1] != ' '
```

or

```
check_strict = lambda my_string: my_string[:12] == ' ' * 12 and my_string[13] != ' '
```

Comment: Requires a parameter `N`. OP seems to want to do this without that parameter

Comment: Was there a specific reason you choose index slicing instead of `str.startswith()`? This seems like the exact use case `startswith()` was designed for...

Comment: Also this answer is wrong - the code in OP's question requires that `count % 4 == 0` ie *exactly* `4*N` spaces are required, and no more.

Comment: @TomWyllie Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lstrip method to strip starting whitespace and then compare the lengths of the stripped and original strings:

```
s = string.lstrip()
return ((len(string) - len(s)) % 4 == 0 and (len(string) - len(s) != 0)
```

(You could even make it one line by not setting a variable for s.)

Comment: And it also returns true for strings that start with 0 spaces.

Comment: Oh true, he did say positive integer. Hold on I will fix

Comment: This doesn't work if the string starts with other whitespace characters

Comment: @timchap I assumed spaces included any whitespace character. If that is an issue you can find and subtract the number of non space whitespace characters with `string[:(len(string)-len(s))].count('\t')` and the same for `\n`

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression works decently for this:

```
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fef988e4780>
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '  ')
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '    ')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fef988e4718>
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', 'foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fef988e4780>
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '  foo')
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '    foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fef988e4718>
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '      foo')
>>> re.match('(?: {4})*(?! )', '        foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fef988e4780>
```

Note that this will allow N to be 0, and works with strings that only contain spaces. A valid match is considered true, but you can pass the result to `bool()` if you want it to be strictly a `bool`. Replacing the `*` with a `+` will force N to be greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
def startsWith4Nspaces(s):
    if not s: return False

    numLeadingSpaces = len(s) - len(s.lstrip(' '))
    if not numLeadingSpaces: return False
    if numLeadingSpaces%4: return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. Note that you can 'slice' a string to get the first four characters. Then you can compare that with the spaces. Here's an example:

```
mystring[:4] == '    '
```

You can also use the `startswith` function of strings:

```
mystring.startswith('    ')
```

Note that if the string starts with 5 or more spaces, both of these approaches will still return True. If you need the method find **exactly 4** starting spaces, a regular expression may be better suited.

If the number of spaces can be a variable, simply use `' '*N` where `N` is the number of spaces to match.

Comment: I'm pretty sure startswith() will perform better than other solutions (esp. using reg ex).

Comment: Any gains versus a regex will be chewed up by iterating to find N and in making sure that there aren't e.g. 6 spaces at the beginning.

Comment: A good point. I will note the caveat that these methods do not consider what happens when there are more than 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
def StartsWith4Nspaces(s):
    diff = len(s) - len(s.lstrip(' '))
    return ((diff > 0) and not (diff%4))

print(StartsWith4Nspaces('abc'))
print(StartsWith4Nspaces(' ' * 1 + 'abc'))
print(StartsWith4Nspaces(' ' * 4 + 'abc'))
print(StartsWith4Nspaces(' ' * 6 + 'abc'))
print(StartsWith4Nspaces(' ' * 8 + 'abc'))
```

Output

```
False
False
True
False
True
```

Basically you remove leading spaces and compare the difference in length of the stripped and the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want *exactly* N spaces - no more, no less - at the start of the string, then use regular expressions;

```
import re    
def starts_with_four_n_spaces(eval_string):
    return re.search(r'^(?:\s{4})+(?!\s).*$', eval_string) is not None
```

Output;

```
>>> starts_with_four_n_spaces('  foo')
False
>>> starts_with_four_n_spaces('        foo')
True
```

The pattern `^(?:\s{4})+(?!\s).*$` works as follows

- `^(?:\s{4})+` Match a multiple of four spaces;
- `(?!\s)` assert that this is not followed by another space;
- `.*$` match anything up until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex answer:

`re.search('[^ ]', string).start() % 4 == 0`

Finds index of the first non-space character and modulos w.r.t. 4.

**Or the same approach with list comprehension:**

`next(i for i, c in enumerate(string) if c != ' ') % 4 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can `slice` the string and use `all()` built-in method to check the sliced `string` is what you need, as the following:

```
st = '    testString'
N = 1
print all(x == ' ' for x in st[:4*N])
```

will output

```
True
```